# working with CNN input shapes - RuntimeError: shape '[32, 3, 8, 12]' is invalid for input of size

Tags: pytorch, conv-neural-network

I am working with an RGB image of a size = (432,288) which is the ratio of (3/2) trying to build a generator using Conv2DTranspose (upsampling) layers.

The noice vector has a shape of (32,96) where 96 is the combination of (12,8)-and again, same aspect ratio of the original image.

The first step I am doing in my forward function is
x = noise.view(32,3,12,8) however this is throuing a runtime error indicating the number of elements in the noise function is not equal to the reshaped value. It works if I replace the #of channels from 3 to 1, however I want to keep my image in RGB format. any leads please?

This is a very simple representation of the code

```
import torch
noise = torch.randn(32, 96)
x = noise.view(32,3,8, 12)
```

and the error is:
`RuntimeError: shape '[32, 3, 8, 12]' is invalid for input of size 3072`

Thank you :)

Comment: You can't just pull numbers out of nowhere. `noise = torch.randn(32, 96)` has `3072` elements. A tensor of size `(32,3,8, 12)` has `9216` elements.

Comment: hi @Karl, In the context of generator and discriminator networks, the 96 is the noise dimensions driven by the ratio of my original image shape. During the Gen. Network layers, I am reshaping the input noise (32,96) in this examples to have 3 Channels as part of the network layers. The traditional noise.view(32,1,8,12) works but results in 1 channel images and I want to have 3 channels as an input

Answer (score 0):

view is simple reshape tensor of your noise variable and it could be exactly 32 * 96 values anyway, that's why you get the error

nn.Conv2d - may be the right choice for the first layer